# Customize Sitecore Content Editor Language Selector

Tags: sitecore, page-editor

I have already customize the Page Editor Language Selector by overriding the webedit command, but I can't figure out how to customize the Content Editor Language Selector:

[image: Content Editor Language Selector]

I am trying to replicate the functionality I added for the Page Editor Language Selector, which sorts the languages by region and then language name, and also adjusts the name to not display the ": language (region)" part.

I have already tried overriding the *Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Globalization.SelectLanguage.SelectLanguagePage* on the SelectLanguage.xaml.xml shell file, but that is for the More Langauges dialog and not for the initial view of the languages. I have also tried overriding the ribbon:languages command, but that is for the click event on each language for actually selecting it.

Any suggestions where else I should look for this functionality?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That menu is generated by `\sitecore\shell\Applications\Content Manager\Galleries\Languages\Gallery Languages.xml` and the associated CodeBeside in `Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.Galleries.Languages.GalleryLanguagesForm, Sitecore.Client`

The rendering of each option is control by `\sitecore\shell\Applications\Content Manager\Galleries\Languages\Gallery Languages.Option.xml` although the values are set from the CodeBeside.

BTW, I just used the Chrome Dev Tools to figure out what was going on. From the Network Panel there is an XHTTP call to `default.aspx?xmlcontrol=Gallery.Languages`. Useful debugging steps.

Comment: Thanks! That is perfect. I saw that querystring when I was in the Chrome Dev Tools but wasn't sure where to follow it.

Comment: Great. Usually, just remove the dot and search for files in /Sitecore/shell/applications but a bit of trial and error sometimes :)